# Python accessing parent class's "with" statement in an overridden method

Tags: python, oop, with-statement, contextmanager

I have a base class whose method uses a `with` statement.  In a child class, I override the same method, and would like to then access that same `with` statement (instead of having two `with` statements).

What are the standard ways of solving this problem?

For an example and possible solution, please see below.

---

**Sample** using `threading.Lock`

```py
from threading import Lock


class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = Lock()
        self._data = 0

    def do_something_locked(self) -> None:
        with self.lock:
            self._data += 5


class ChildClass(BaseClass):
    def do_something_locked(self) -> None:
        super().do_something_locked()
        # Obviously the parent class's self.lock's __exit__ method has 
        # already been called.  What are accepted methods to add more 
        # functionality inside parent class's "with" statement?
        with self.lock:
            self._data += 1
```

---

**Possible Solution**

My first inclination is to define a private method in the `BaseClass` like so:

```py
    def do_something_locked(self) -> None:
        with self.lock:
            self._do_something()

    def _do_something(self) -> None:
        self._data += 5
```

And then the `ChildClass` can just override `_do_something`.  This will work fine.

I am wondering, are there any other common patterns of solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a re-entrant Lock. This will automatically "connect" the nested `with` statements, releasing the lock only after the outer-most `with`.

```py
from threading import RLock


class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lock = RLock()
        self._data = 0

    def do_something_locked(self) -> None:
        with self.lock:
            self._data += 5


class ChildClass(BaseClass):
    def do_something_locked(self) -> None:
        with self.lock:
            super().do_something_locked()
            self._data += 1
```

In general, the pattern of [reentrant context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#reentrant-cms) exists explicitly to allow possibly-nested contexts.

> These context managers can not only be used in multiple with statements, but may also be used inside a with statement that is already using the same context manager.

Answer (score 2):

> My first inclination is to define a private method in the `BaseClass` like so... And then the `ChildClass` can just override `_do_something`. This will work fine.

This is a good approach to the problem, [even when you don't have a special requirement](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/CallSuper.html) (like needing to remain within a `with` block context). I would not use a leading underscore for the "hook" method name, because anything that you are expecting to be overridden in derived classes, is logically part of the class interface. Also, if the `self._data += 5` part always needs to happen, then leave it in `do_something_locked`.

> are there any other common patterns of solving this problem?

Specific to the problem, you could use a re-entrant lock as shown in the other answer. You could also ignore the fact that the classes are related, and use dependency injection - make a general method in the base class that accepts a callable and executes it, using the lock:

```
# in base class
def do_locked(self, what, *args, **kwargs):
    with self.lock:
        what(*args, **kwargs)

# in derived class
def _implementation(self):
    pass
def do_interesting_thing(self):
    # pass in our own bound method, which takes no arguments
    self._do_locked(self._implementation)
```

This way allows for client code to make use of the lock in custom ways. It's probably not a great idea if you don't need or want that functionality.